# How to display only the db2 query result via shell script and not the query?

Tags: sql, shell, db2

There is probably a very simple solution here, but I am probably not using the right search terms. I have a sql query running in a shell script. I get the results I am looking for, however, I am also getting the sql query as part of of the result. How can I suppress this and just show the result?

My script:

```
#!/usr/bin/sh

db2 connect to MYDB >/dev/null 2>&1;
db2 -x -v "select A, B, C from MYTABLE";
db2 connect reset >/dev/null 2>&1;
```

And my output looks like this:

```
select A, B, C from MYTABLE
AAA   BBB   CCC
AAA   BBB   CCC
```

I would like to get rid of the first row and just show the result. What am I missing?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: do you just want to get rid of *the first row* ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-v` option for the DB2 command line processor causes the current statement being executed to be printed in the output.

Remove the `-v` from your command and you'll get only the results of the query.

Comment: Thank you! This goes in the category of one of my dumbest questions, but had to ask;)

Answer (score 3):

if you just want to skip the 1st row from your output you could:

```
yourscript.sh | tail -n +2
```

test with seq:

```
kent$  seq 5|tail -n +2  
2
3
4
5
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

db2 -o query

for more info. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/adamache/0109adamache.html